# ASP WebForms file download works only sometimes

Tags: asp.net, download, webforms

I developed code to add/remove/download files to orders and it works good. Downloading code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = GetContentType(fileExtension);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Everything works good when code is in OnItemCommand method in DataList.

```
protected void dlAttachemnts_OnItemCommand(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "btnDeleteAttachemnt")
    {
        ...
    }

    if (e.CommandName == "btnDownloadAttachment")
    {
        // Download
    }
}
```

But when code is in Click method in button on other page downloading doesn't work.

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Download
}
```

I get HttpUnhandledException in Application_Error() in Global.asax.cs with message "Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent".

I double checked filePath, fileExtension etc and it is ok.

I suspect that I am sending both file nad page same time, but I am not familiar with Web Forms and I am not sure how to check it and what to do (app is very old, big and with code legacy).

Thank you for help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own changing button into link

Before:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="btnDownload_Click" />
```

After:

```
<a class="input-button-lookalike" href="/DownloadHandler.ashx?
   fileName=myFile.txt" target='"_blank"'>Download</a>
```

I also added style input-button-lookalike so as the link looks good with other buttons and added handler DownloadHandler.ashx with code:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {
      var fileName = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"];
      // Download as in question
 }
```